# What is the best way to select records from value/unit table?

Tags: postgresql

I have `hard_drives` table with columns `producent, size, unit`

```
samsung|256|GB
caviar |850|MB
sandisc|512|GB
seagate|2  |TB
```

I'd like to create queries for selecting hard drives with `size > 128GB`, `size < 1000MB`, `size < 1TB` etc.

Would you add new column like `size_in_bytes`, or create some conversion table like `storage_units` with columns `unit, size_in_bytes` and use it for calculations, or maybe there is some better way to perform such queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a common unit, probably MB, for storing all disk sizes.  As a workaround, you can use a `CASE` expression in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    CASE WHEN unit = 'MB' THEN size
         WHEN unit = 'GB' THEN 1000*size
         WHEN unit = 'TB' THEN 1000*1000*size END > 128*1000   -- size > 128GB
```